# How to configure a server

Tags: server, configure

I have 8 computers, a switch and a modem. They all run windows 7 and connected to a windows 7 server. I replaced the clients with Ubuntu 12.04.3 and uninstalled the proxy from the windows 7 server and now I can connect to the internet on all clients. The issue is that I want to replace the Windows 7 server with Ubuntu 12.04.3 but I don't know how to configure it so that it can connect to the internet and share it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is using your Windows 7 server machine as a Masq/NAT router, and probably as a firewall as well.  I have found the `Shorewall` package to be an excellent, and user friendly package to assist in this task.  This howto guide should get you pointed in the right direction:

http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm

If you have any more questions or troubles, I know quite a bit about `Shorewall`, and would be willing to help.

Comment: many thanks for your help bro! but is there any software that can do things automatically!

Comment: Shorewall does it automatically.